# CSS alignment problem in microsoft edge (on mobile)

Tags: css, vue.js, mobile, alignment, microsoft-edge

[image]

Only when I use microsoft edge on mobile I have this problem. I use the following css for those buttons:

```
.footer-wrapper a i[class^="cfi"] {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It's something I miss? Or there is any way to use devtools on mobile? Because when I use any user agent on my laptop everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the full context, seeing the HTML would be helpful. However, the easiest way to do that would be to flex-center them.

```
.footer-wrapper a i[class^="cfi"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```